# Distinct random in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

From documentation I see that `cast(random() * 1000 as int)` gives a random integer between 1 and 1000. However, I am getting alot of duplicates- is there a way to get a distinct random number? To clarify, total records is <1000

Comment: I'd expect these results when the function is evaluated after the results are calculated. This is normally a fairly obvious optimization for the engine to make: `random()` itself isn't going to be affected by any of the results from the rest of the query, so run it after it's finished executing the rest instead of for every *candidate* row.

Please provide a verifiable example so we can get you to a final answer. The details of what you're doing may influence those answers. I'm not a redshift  person, so can't answer in detail off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign random numbers using `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by random())
```

That seems sufficient for most purposes.  You can scale these to 1000:

```
select trunc(1000 * (row_number() over (order by random()) * 1.0 / count(*) over () ))
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect!

Answer (score 0):

the way to replicate this might be to select much more numbers than you need (x2 or x3) in a subquery and then select distinct out of that subquery